# Evaluate limit of a sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For a fixed real number $a>0$ I have to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\left(\sqrt{k+a}-\sqrt{k}\right)$$

Any hints?

Comment: I can evaluate it for $a=1$, cause then its equivalent to Lebesgue integral for function $f(x)=x^2$ and value will be $\frac{1}{3}$, but for other real numbers i'm a bit stuck

Comment: In general, it's $a/3.$ You can use the Stolz–Cesàro theorem to prove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\left(\sqrt{k+a}-\sqrt{k}\right)$. For any $n\geq 2$ we have:

$$ A_{n}-A_{n-1} = n\left(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}\right) = \frac{an}{\sqrt{n+a}+\sqrt{n}}\sim \frac{a}{2}\sqrt{n} \tag{1}$$
and by setting $B_n = n^{3/2}$ we have $B_n-B_{n-1}\sim \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{n}$.
 By the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) it follows that the wanted limit is $\color{red}{\large\frac{a}{3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \dfrac1n*\dfrac{ak/n}{\sqrt{k/n+a/n}+\sqrt {k/n}}$

$=\int_0^1\dfrac{ax}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt x}dx $

$=∫_0^1 a\sqrt{x}/2dx $

$=a\big[\dfrac13x^{3/2}\big]_0^1$

$= \dfrac{a}{3}$